# java console error about touch navigation

Tags: javascript

can anyone help me decode this with what this error from the console is trying to tell me? I have searched Google but cant not find specifics about this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined
at removeAllFocusStates (touch-keyboard-navigation.js?ver=20181231:190)
at HTMLDocument. (touch-keyboard-navigation.js?ver=20181231:313)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, whatever is right in front of `.querySelectorAll` is not found.

So for example, `thisObject.querySelectorAll`, `thisObject` is not defined so the function fails finding all the elements that that function is looking for when there is no object to query within. There would need to be more code to be able to figure out why that might be as there is not enough here to give a more concrete answer.

Comment: thanks so in this instance it is undefined?

Comment: Yes. I can't tell what the variable is because you didn't post that part of the code but it should be apparent as you just need to find what is calling ```.querySelectorAll``` in your code.

Comment: tanks that was the whole string from the console which is why I was confused